# SwiftUI UIScrollView content can be scrolled out of frame

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit

I implemented a UIScrollView from UIKit in SwiftUI (without storyboard) because there is nothing similar in SwiftUI. It works quite well so far, but the ScrollView is not limited by the size of the content, but you can still scroll over the edge of the content. The stronger the zoom factor, the stronger this effect becomes apparent.

UIScrollView Wrapper in SwiftUI:

```swift
struct ZoomableScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var didZoom: Bool

    private var content: Content

    init(didZoom: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        _didZoom = didZoom
        self.content = content()
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator 
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true

        let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
        hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        hostedView.backgroundColor = .black
        scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)

        return scrollView
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: self.content), didZoom: $didZoom)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = self.content
        assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {

        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
        @Binding var didZoom: Bool

        init(hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>, didZoom: Binding<Bool>) {
            self.hostingController = hostingController
            _didZoom = didZoom
        }

        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return hostingController.view
        }

        func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
            didZoom = !(scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale)
        }
    }
}
```

SwiftUI ContentView:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      ZoomableScrollView {
          Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 420, height: 600)
      }
   }
}
```

[image: GIF that visualizes the problem.]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve so far? This behavior is because the initial scroll size is smaller than the viewport. You may want to customize it inside the delegate if you want different behavior.

Comment: Set `scrollView.backgroundColor = .red` to see what is happening.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini How can I customize the initial scroll size?

Comment: Using frame (`in your case`). What is your desired behavior?

Comment: I want the content of the UIScrollView to behave like a page in Apple's Pages or Word.

Answer (score 1):

You're making whole screen zoomable if you want to make only rectangle zoomable then only wrap that rectangle within zoomablescrollview

```
 struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
  ZStack{
   ZoomableScrollView {
      Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 420, height: 600)
    }.frame(width: 420,height: 600)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't work for me!